# Failure while installing ruby plugin in webstorm

Tags: ruby, plugins, webstorm

After enabling the ruby plugin in WebStorm it starts with the folowing error message:

```
Plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby failed to initialize and will be disabled:
com/intelij/debugger/settings/NodeRenderSettings
Please restart JetBrains WebStorm.
```

Anyone knows what happens here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm has no support for Ruby plug-in, it's designed only for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. It's a known issue of the plugins repository that incompatible plug-ins are allowed to be installed, we are working on it.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a simple plugin for ruby code highlighting.

Comment: No, but you can try to create a custom file type: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/new-file-type.html.

Answer (score 0):

See this solution, it applied for webstorm too. 
[Is it possible to get Ruby syntax highlighting in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451359/is-it-possible-to-get-ruby-syntax-highlighting-in-phpstorm)

But it for highlighting only.
It's worked for me.