# Webstorm: ColdFusion Syntax

Tags: coldfusion, webstorm

Is there a way to get ColdFusion syntax highlighting in Web storm 8? Has anyone been successful with this? If not where would one begin to start or what is something that can be done to get this option available? I currently use web storm for everything and it is a great editor but most of my code at the moment is in cold fusion and I would really like to just do everything in a single editor. I'm not sure if this is the place to go to ask something like this but hopefully someone can help out.

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm doesn't have support for ColdFusion. You should try [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for that.

Comment: Even having a plugin just for Cold fusion syntax highlighting? I don't need it to run the cold fusion code I just hate looking at white color cold fusion code.

Comment: If all you need is some basic syntax highlighting, you can either create a new file type in Settings/File Types, add .cfml as a registered pattern there, and define your own syntax highlighting rules, or search for existing textmate bundles for CFML on the web, import them and use for the .cfml syntax highlighting - see http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/05/textmate-bundles-in-phpstorm/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16451778/2000323 for more info

Comment: It's ironic don't you think that 'WEB'storm the web ide doesn't have support for a web lanugage, but a java dev ide does... haha. that's just lame management by jetbrains. 

It would take litrally 2 seconds to add it and it would make webstorm a viable ide for cf.