# Maxscript in any jetbrais IDE?

Tags: ide, editor, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, maxscript

there is currently maxscript programming support inside sublime text.

I was wondering bacause now the syntax highlighting and everything alreay exists for maxscript, how to go about it to make maxscript a supported programming language inside other ide's or editors?

The jetbrains applications comes to mind first (webstorm etc.)
or even inside open online IDE's like Ace of Codemirror.

Because that would be great.

Does anyone knows if that is at all possible, and how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

None of JetBrains IDEs provide support for maxscript:(, and I'm not aware of any custom plugins for this language. 
If all you need is a basic syntax highlighting, you can either try searching for MaxSript textmate bundles (see [Is it possible to get Ruby syntax highlighting in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451359/is-it-possible-to-get-ruby-syntax-highlighting-in-phpstorm/16451778#16451778)) or register your own file type, defining a syntax highlighting for it (http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/new-file-type.html).
If none of these options look suitable for you, try developing your own language plugins - see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with MaxScript syntax plugin. The syntax highlighting and overall coding experience is close to perfect.

[image]

Example of MaxScript syntax highlighting you may see here:

[image]