# WebStorm 2016.3 missing Template Data Language (Velocity and FreeMarker)

Tags: templates, webstorm, velocity, jetbrains-ide

I am currently using JS and velocity in my project.
I stumbled upon [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/template-languages-velocity-and-freemarker.html).

But I cant find the template data language for Velocity and FreeMarker.

I am currently using a trial version. Is this only available on the full purchased version?

Comment: Velocity templates are not supported in WebStorm. That page got into the online help by mistake and is being removed. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Please also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688199/velocity-syntax-highlighting-in-webstorm