# Vagrantfile syntax highlight in PyCharm

Tags: syntax, vagrant, pycharm, vagrantfile

I use Vagrant plugin for running VMs, but I still desire to set up Vagrantfile syntax highlight in PyCharm.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vagrantfile is written as a Ruby source file. So if you can get Ruby syntax highlighting to work in PyCharm, it'll work for vagrant files by default. See the following question and answer, it applies to PyCharm:

[Is it possible to get Ruby syntax highlighting in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451359/is-it-possible-to-get-ruby-syntax-highlighting-in-phpstorm/16451778#16451778)

**tldr**:

Git clone the following repo somewhere (e.g. **~/PyCharm_Misc/** ):

**https://github.com/textmate/ruby.tmbundle**

Then add the repo's folder ( **~/PyCharm_Misc/ruby.tmbundle** ) as a "TextMate Bundle" inside PyCharm in the following menu:

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> TextMate Bundles**

Comment: Works for me! Pycharm 5 on Mac