# How to add ReactJS support with .tsx and .jsx syntax highlighting / code complete to IntelliJ Idea 14

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

It seems the [newer versions of Intelli-J](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-reactjs-in-javascript-and-typescript.html) Idea support this natively.  Any way to add support for version 14?  I couldn't find a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, it's not possible. IntelliJ platform has evolved a lot since version 14 and many new plug-in features depend on the new platform features and APIs, therefore backporting this functionality to the older IDE versions is not an easy task and is not worth it.

For the basic syntax highlighting you could try TextMate Bundles support feature. There is [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451778/104891) explaining how to make it work for Ruby, but for other files types it would be similar. Note that this will not provide the code completion.

If you are on a tight budget and cannot afford upgrading to the latest version, you may consider using WebStorm instead.

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I was hoping for, but definitive.