# Freemarker highlighting in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, syntax-highlighting, freemarker

Unfortunately, JetBrains do not offer FTL (Freemarker) highlighting in WebStorm and I really miss that. Buying IntelliJ IDEA is not a solution for me. So I'm looking for some workaround here. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity/FreeMarker support in only available IntellJ IDEA Ultimate. Unfortunately migrating it to WebStorm is not an easy task, as Velocity plugin heavily relies on Java... So currently we have no plans to provide Freemarker/Velocity template engine support in WebStorm. If you miss this feature and purchasing Idea is not an option for you, please feel free to file a request for providing Velocity support to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB.
Also I can suggest searching for existing textmate bundles for Velocity files on the web - you can then import them and use for the Velocity syntax highlighting; see http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/05/textmate-bundles-in-phpstorm/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16451778/2000323 for more info